# Random ID in Firebase and Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have a function that creates a client number with a secret in my firebase DB.

```
    vm.createNumbers = function ($scope, $vm, $window) {
        var clientNumbers = $firebaseObject(ref.child('clientNumbers'));
        var id = Math.floor( 100 * Math.random() );
        clientNumbers.$loaded().then(function () {
            var newNumber = {
                id: {
                    number : vm.number,
                    secret : vm.secret,
                    assigned : false,
                }
            }

            clientNumbers.$ref().set(newNumber);
        })
    }
```

I am trying to use the var `id` as the key holder for the firebase DB. Right now, it stores it as `id` instead of something like `098678` so my structure looks like this:

```
clientNumbers {
  id: {
     number: 20398973802387980,
     secret: 24987987,
     assigned: false
  }
}
```

You can imagine, when I go to create another insertion, the existing one gets updated rather than creating a new one, because the "primary id" is the same as the one already in firebase.

Preferably, I would like to get the last inserted "id" and increase it by one for the next insertion.

I'm coming to this from Codeigniter, PHP, and MySQL so I have a learning curve. Apologies in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From the Firebase Documentation....

For the ways of saving data.

> `set( )`  Write or replace data to a defined path, like     messages/users/username
>
> `push( )` Add to a list of data in the database. Every time you call `push()` your database generates a unique ID, like messages/users/unique-id/username

I was using the `set()` way and that is not the correct way for what I was trying to accomplish.

I changed

```
clientNumbers.$ref().set(newNumber);
```

To

```
clientNumbers.$ref().push(newNumber);
```

While this doesn't solve my "incremental id" problem, it works for now. Maybe I can tackle that within each data set.

Comment: Monotonically incrementing ids (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3...) are a bad strategy when you are in a massively multi-user environment. All users must agree on what the next id will be, which creates a synchronization bottleneck. That's why Firebase provides its `push` operation. It has the same ordering guarantees as you'd get with indexes, but without the synchronization problems. So you should really wonder *why* you need those indexes to be monotonic. It is very likely that you don't really need them. Many devs pick them, just because they're familiar.